# Getting java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format while testing code related to AWSS3 in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, mockito, junit5

I have to read s3 object from s3Bucket and process that fetched object. Based on that processing I will generate one map. But while running the test I'm getting Not in GZIP format exception. Can anyone help me with this issue?

I'm using mockito for testing purpose

Code to test:

```
public Map getAndProcessFile(){
  
    try {
      S3Object fileObj = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, key));

      Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new GZIPInputStream(fileObj.getObjectContent()));

      Map<Boolean, List<CompletableFuture>> resultMap = processFile(fileIn);
     return resultMap;
  } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error("Error occurred while processing file with key : {}",
                objectSummary.getKey());
      return null;
  }
 }
```

Test Method :

```
    @Test
    public void testScanAndProcessS3Object_whenKeysFound() throws Exception {
     String decode = URLDecoder.decode("dummyString", "UTF-8");
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(decode.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream = new S3ObjectInputStream(in, new 
                                              HttpGet("dummyRequest"));
    s3Object.setObjectContent(s3ObjectInputStream);
    s3Object.setBucketName(BUCKET_NAME);
    s3Object.setKey("000000295027.gz");

    when(s3Client.getObject(anyString())).thenReturn(s3Object);

    Map map = processService.getAndProcessFile();

    assertNotNull(map);
}
```

Stack Trace :

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
    at com.gofynd.job.ETLS3Pipeline.lambda$processObject$0(ETLS3Pipeline.java:109)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:401)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:734)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:583)
```

Comment: Same issue for me, any solutions you have got?